# Variable assignment inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I just can not figure out what's going on with this for loop.
It assigns a `User` variable on every loop. But after the first loop, `reader.read()` is not called anymore (I debugged it), and `user` is always `user1`

Any clues?

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserReader reader = new UserReader();
        for( User user = reader.read(); user != null; ){
           System.out.println(user); // always "user1" 
        }
   }
}

public class UserReader {

    private Iterator<User> users;

    public ItemReaderImpl() {
        this.users = mock().iterator();
    }

    public User read() {
         return users.hasNext() ?
              users.next() : null;
    }

    private static List<User> mock() {
         List<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();
         users.add(new User("user1"));
         users.add(new User("user2"));
         users.add(new User("user3"));
         users.add(new User("user4"));
         users.add(new User("user5"));
         return users;
    }
}
```

Output

BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
BOOM
to infinity

Comment: Well the read() happens during the initialization part of the for loop so no surprise it only gets called once, what is your question?

Comment: Try `for( User user = reader.read(); user != null; user = reader.read())`

Comment: @ThomasJungblut is correct... The read() only gets called during initialization and the iterator doesn't move forward. So, it gets stuck on user1.

Comment: Here is where, IMHO, a while loop is clearer than a for loop.

Comment: Well everyone is right, i was missing the reassignment on each loop like @JanGassen suggested. Thanks